# PHP show logged in user from domain1 a button on domain2

Tags: session, authentication, drupal, dns, cross-domain

I am developing a site in `Drupal` (`Site1`). On this site (`Site1`), there is a banner/link advertising a competition. The competition is only open to users who come to `Site1` from another site (`Site2`). Users from `Site2` need to be logged in to access the link to `Site1`.

Once the logged-in user from `Site2` lands on `Site1`, the site will display the competition banner/link. If user arrives directly to `Site1`, they see a different banner/link and wont be able to proceed to the competitions page.

How do I go about implementing this? What does the developer from `Site2` need to provide me with?  What do I have to do on my `Site1` to accept the user from `Site2` and display the said competition banner/link.

Comment: Have you considered implementing a Web Service? Here is a good module for this: https://www.drupal.org/project/services

Comment: Thank you, vitorsdcs.  I will have a look and let you know if it works.